# Problems with shanwan usb wireless gamepad

Tags: usb

i tried to use that usb shanwan controller and the left analog and dpad maps the same, but the problem is the home/select button doesnt work, so the left analog keeps activating the dpad, someone could help me?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].